# Вызвать асинхронный метод обьекта через multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, multiprocessing

1. Есть асинхронный метод обьекта, пытаюсь его вызвать через multiprocessing.Process перед этим обернув в asyncio.run, это срабатывает, но процесс блокируется и невозможно запустить несколько процессов параллельно, приходится ждать завершения текущего.

---

2. Далее я перешел к другому решению и создал у класса новый не асинхронный метод внутри которого происходил вызов асинхронного метода этого же класса через asyncio.run. Это работает но процесс попрежнему блокируется как и в первом случае.

---

3. Создал функцию из которой вызвал не асинхронный метод внутри которого происходил вызов асинхронного метода этого же класса через asyncio.run. Это работает прекрасно в многопотоке. Но проблема что предтся создавать функцию для каждого обьекта. В аргументах multiprocessing.Process нельзя передать обьект. Метод кривой но каким то образом работает.

---

4. Так же я пробовал передавать обьекты аргументами в функцию через multiprocessing.Pool это не работало когда в аргументах обьект.

Я исчерпал все методы и не знаю как решить эту проблему...

Python 3.8

P.S. Забыл отписать что у меня все работало через ThreadPool, но асинхронное выполнение двух задач было медленным. Асихронность досталась от библиотеки puppeteer нет возможности использовать ее синхронную версию, так как ее просто нет.

Comment: Зачем здесь вообще multiprocessing? Если вы хотите запустить несколько асинхронных методов параллельно, просто используйте asyncio.create_task и всё

Comment: @andreymal бывает нужна дикая смесь из ИО и ЦПУ =)
https://github.com/alex-eri/uradius/blob/870cc2ee6f370044091108d0d1420786355db534/radius/server.pyx#L21-L37

Comment: слишком медленное исполнение, в отдельных процессах намного лучше. не могу понять как туда экземпляр класса запихать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, суть в том что multiprocessing использует pickle для сериализации обьектов, и он скорее всего неправильно обрабатывает обьект класса.
Как замену стандартному multiprocessing использовал pathos.
Он использует dill для сериализации обьектов, обработает все типы что ему скормите.

Answer (score 0):

`asyncio.run` это почти синглтон, который работает один раз. Для запуска асинхронщины в попроцесса используйте `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop(); loop.run_until_complete(async_foo())` внутри процесса. Но...

Мультипроцессинг и методы класса не совместимые понятия потому как класс не передается в процесс, а только копируется при старте процесса.

Для запуска синхронной тяжелой работы в асинхронном приложении существуют [экзекуторы](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), а асинхронные функции вполне работают в тасках.